# Cut and paste from eclipse into MS word appears as large blue blob

Tags: eclipse

This has been bothering me for years. Every time I cut a block of code from a java file in eclipse and paste into a word document, the text just appears as a big block of text. Does anyone know of a  way to fix this?

Comment: I am not sure why it is not working for you. But my works perfectly fine. I am using word 2013 and eclipse Europa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pasting your code into a basic text editor first, like notepad; it should get rid of any attributes that are coming from where you cut from.

EDIT

See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/control-the-formatting-when-you-paste-text-HA010215708.aspx and look for the "Keep Text Only" option.

Comment: This is what I end up usually doing, but it's really not optimal.

Comment: See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/control-the-formatting-when-you-paste-text-HA010215708.aspx and look for the "Keep Text Only" option.

Comment: Thanks, I never noticed that option before. If you add the link to your original answer, I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 5):

This mostly happens with single line copying. Try copying by including the white-space from the above/bottom line.

Answer (score 1):

This is well known problem. It is registered as a Eclipse bug:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=86503

Unfortunately, for today, this problem is not solved.